# How can I declare a 5x5 grid of numbers in Python?

Tags: python

How would I declare this? I'm thinking something along the lines of:

```
boardPieces = ["A","O","A"
               "A", "A", "O"
              ]
```

Comment: You say you want to declare a grid of Numbers. But in your example, it looks like you want a grid of Strings. Could you clarify?

Comment: Why do you use the word "declare"?  Python has no "declaration".  What do you mean by "declare"?  Do you mean "create" or "assign"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming a 2d matrix? Something like this should work.

```
boardPieces = [["A","O","A","A", "A"],["A","O","A","A", "A"],["A","O","A","A", "A"],["A","O","A","A", "A"],["A","O","A","A", "A"]]
```

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the answers given - if you need to do work with 2D (or higher dimension) arrays in Python, a very good library for this purpose is Numpy - [Link](https://numpy.org/).

Among others, it lets you easily "reshape" an array in whatever logical form fits you at a particular moment (for example, an list of 6 values can be treated as any of the following arrays - 1x6, 2x3, 3x2, ...).

The output of this code -

```
import numpy

boardPieces = numpy.array( [ "A", "O", "A", "A", "A", "O" ], numpy.character )
boardPieces = boardPieces.reshape( [ 2, 3 ] )
print boardPieces
boardPieces = boardPieces.reshape( [ 3, 2 ] )
print boardPieces
```

Would be -

```
[['A' 'O' 'A']
 ['A' 'A' 'O']]
[['A' 'O']
 ['A' 'A']
 ['A' 'O']]
```

Might not be suitable for your particular use-case, but can serve as a reference for others.

Answer (score 2):

```
[[0] * 5 for x in range(5)]
```

or

```
[[0 for x in range(5)] for y in range(5)]
```

The first will only work with immutable types, while the second will work with any type.

Comment: I didn't down-vote it. But I think it was down-voted because the first example doesn't work. It creates an array like: [ [0], [0], [0], ...]

Answer (score 0):

Just do like this.

```
[["A","O","A","O","A"],[...],[...],[...],[...]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Creating a 5x5 matrix of zeroes

```
ls = [[0]*5]*5
print(ls)

Output:
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Similarly a matrix of string type values

```
ls = [['A','O','A','A','A']]*5
print(ls)

Output: 
[['A', 'O', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
 ['A', 'O', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
 ['A', 'O', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
 ['A', 'O', 'A', 'A', 'A'],
 ['A', 'O', 'A', 'A', 'A']]
```

Comment: Sorry but it is an inappropriate solution. You create a matrix with 5 pointers to the same 1D array. To prove that, modify a cell and print the matrix. You will see that your modification is at 5 different places.